# How to drop excel rows using pandas based on an "OR" statement for 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a spreadsheet with about 4000 rows.  One of the columns is named "com" ( not my doing ) with values of com, gov or org.  I have these three statements, the first 2 work great when I only want to keep com or gov but the 3rd drops everything when I want to drop anything that is NOT com or gov.:

- ```
  combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame[combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'] != "com"].index, inplace = True)
  ```
- ```
  combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame[combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'] != "gov"].index, inplace = True)
  ```
- combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame[(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'] != "com") | (combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'] != "gov")].index, inplace = True)

Unfortunately it's dropping all rows on the 3rd option.

Help?

Comment: To reduce visible noise, you might consider using `df` instead of `combinedMonthVulnDataFrame`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pair a mask with a list of to filter your records. By using a mask you don't need to drop by using the indices of the records, you will be dropping records based on wether they meet the criteria "True/False", whereas

```
data =  [["com", "Namespace", "Deployment", "Component", "CVE", "Severity"],
 ["dev-stable", "default", "arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a", "ansi-regex", "CVE-2021-3807", "IMPORTANT"],
 ["demo-gov", "default", "arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a", "ansi-regex", "CVE-2021-3807", "IMPORTANT"],
 ["com", "rocketchat", "rocketchat-quantinuum", "coreutils", "CVE-2016-2781", "LOW"],
 ["utilities", "default", "deployments-webserver", "libonig", "CVE-2019-16163", "MODERATE"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])


mask = df['com'].isin(['com'])
df[~mask]


#       com         Namespace   Deployment                  Component
# 2     com         rocketchat  rocketchat-quantinuum       coreutils
```

Then you could also negate the mask if you want records not in your list, whereas

```
mask = df['com'].isin(['com'])
df[~mask]

#       com         Namespace   Deployment                  Component
# 0     dev-stable  default     arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a ansi-regex
# 1     demo-gov    default     arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a ansi-regex
# 3     utilities   default     deployments-webserver       libonig
```

This pattern is pretty flexible and easy to make changes to. It's one approach.

Comment: This looks great but i just tried it and it also drops everything, including some where the column is empty, as well as some where it's "demo-gov".

Comment: You are changing the values in the lists to make it match the logic you want?

Comment: Maybe post a sample of your dataset so we can see exactly what you're working with?

Comment: I updated the code above to this:
<br/>

`mask = combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'].isin(['com','gov'])
combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(df[mask].index, inplace = True)`

Comment: My dataset looks like this:

`com Namespace Deployment Component CVE Severity
dev-stable default arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a ansi-regex CVE-2021-3807 IMPORTANT
dev-stable default arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a ansi-regex CVE-2021-3807 IMPORTANT
com rocketchat rocketchat-quantinuum coreutils CVE-2016-2781 LOW
utilities default deployments-webserver libonig CVE-2019-16163 MODERATE`

( Sorry, I suck at formatting in comments )

Comment: Which of these are the column names?

Comment: The headers are:

`com Namespace Deployment Component CVE Severity`

The first of the data is:

`dev-stable default arango-agnt-zqdd3ekj-35ba4a ansi-regex CVE-2021-3807 IMPORTANT`

Comment: Updated answer to reflect changes given your dataset. Does this work for you?

Comment: The original answer works, it's the 'OR' version of if it's in "com" or "gov" that's failing.  I'm currently getting this:


`combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop[mask].index, inplace = True)`

and the code looks like this:


`mask = combinedMonthVulnDataFrame['com'].isin(['com','gov'])
combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop(combinedMonthVulnDataFrame.drop[mask].index, inplace = True)`